# How to check if API requests response time are longer than 1000 milliseconds in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I tested the 100 requests at a time. Requests minimum time 400ms and maximum time 1200ms.So I would like to check if API requests are longer than 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JMeter Duration assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) for that purpose. Just add the assertion under your API request and input 1000 (ms) as a duration.